# Разделение списка на части

Tags: python, списки

Здравствуйте, как мне разделить вложенный список на примерно равные части?
Допустим есть `list = [[document0],[document1],[document2],[document3],[document4],[document5],[document6]]`
Таких вложенных документов может быть около 20000. В итоге нужно получить

```
part0 = [[document0],[document1]]
part1 = [[document2],[document3]]
part2 = [[document4],[document5],[document6]]
```

Comment: В чём логика разбиения? Почему в первых двух по два элемента, а в последнем три?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что если список из 20 000 элементов разбить на списки по два элемента и присвоить разным переменным,то получится 10 000 переменных? Вы действительно этого хотите?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в списке около 25000 вложенных списков, каждый вложенный список - текстовый файл с набором терминов. Мне нужно провести некоторые преобразования в списке, но т.к данных ооооочень много, то просто напросто не хватает памяти для выполнения операций. И единственное что пришло в голову это разбить список на части, провести вычисления, а потом снова его склеить

Comment: @Midnight, укажите в вопросе что из себя представляют document0 и т.д. Если вы просто распределите те же данные по отдельным, памяти данные меньше занимать не будут. Если там действительно содержимое каких-то файлов, просто не грузите все файлы в память сразу, а обрабатывайте постепенно.

Comment: @insolor, Пример document0 = ['i','love','you']

Comment: @Midnight, средний размер такого списка? Откуда они берутся? Есть ли возможность не грузить их все 20000 в память?

Comment: @insolor, от 15  до 500 терминов, предварительно обработанные и загруженные в список

Comment: @Midnight, я все еще не вижу, в какой момент может не хватить памяти, и чем разбиение на отдельные списки тут может помочь. Было бы лучше, если бы вы более полно описали задачу в вопросе.

Comment: @insolor, есть 25к текстовых документов, в них находятся отзывы о фильмах, в программе я их обрабатываю(привожу к  нижнему регистру, удаляю стоп слова и тд. После мне нужно каждое слово заменить на число вычисленное по определенной формуле  и тут возникает проблема нехватки памяти

Answer (score 2):

Для больших списков чаще Numpy работает быстрее:

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: part0, part1, part2 = np.array_split(lst, 3)

In [14]: part0
Out[14]:
array([['document0'],
       ['document1'],
       ['document2']], dtype='<U9')

In [15]: part1
Out[15]:
array([['document3'],
       ['document4']], dtype='<U9')

In [16]: part2
Out[16]:
array([['document5'],
       ['document6']], dtype='<U9')
```

Answer (score 1):

Разделить произвольный список `xs` на `parts` частей можно с помощью срезов. Вынесем код в отдельную функцию `parting(xs, parts)`:

```
from math import ceil
def parting(xs, parts):
    part_len = ceil(len(xs)/parts)
    return [xs[part_len*k:part_len*(k+1)] for k in range(parts)]
```

Проверяем в интерпретаторе:

```
>>> xs = list(range(20)); print(xs)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> parts = 3
>>> parting(xs, parts)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Последний элемент списка всегда будет меньше остальных, кроме случаев, когда `len(xs)` нацело делится на `parts`.