# Как разделить список на две части по определенному индексу?

Tags: python, list, индексы

Есть два списка с элементами, в первом множество значений, например - `[100,200,1200,1500,2000]`, во втором одно значение `[2]`. Как разделить первый список на две части, что бы в первой части оказались все элементы списка до индекса 2 - (цифра из второго списка) а в другом списке все элементы с индексами >= 2?

На входе:

```
y=[100,200,1200,1500,2000];
z=[2]
```

На выходе:

```
y1=[100,200];
y2=[1200,1500,2000]
```

Comment: а зачем у вас одно значение в список запихнуто?

Comment: Наверное потому что так надо. Тут описана часть ситуации, это число получено из другого списка, путем удаления не нужных элементов, поэтому оно одно в списке осталось. Весь код сюда присылать не вижу смысла. Как правило никто не будет копаться в чужом коде, поэтому сократила до минимума.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разделение списка на части](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811008/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте срезы:

```
y = [100,200,1200,1500,2000]
z = 2

y1, y2 = y[:z], y[z:]
```